# How to get height of element with index value

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var autoHeight = '';
    var items = $('.iosSlider .slider .item');
    var CountNumber = items.size();
    var sliderHeight = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= CountNumber - 1; i++) {
        alert('hi') var itemBox = items.eq[i];
        var itemHeight = itemBox.height();
        alert(itemHeight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) is a function, so invoke it by using `()` - so use `items.eq(i)` instead of `items.eq[i]`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var autoHeight = '';
    var items = $('.iosSlider .slider .item');
    var CountNumber = items.size();
    var sliderHeight = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < CountNumber; i++) {
        alert('hi');
        var itemBox = items.eq(i);
        var itemHeight = itemBox.height();
        alert(itemHeight);
    }
});
```

---

You can also have a look at the [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate through a jQuery object like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var autoHeight = '';
    var items = $('.iosSlider .slider .item');
    var sliderHeight = 0;
    items.each(function (i, item) {
        alert('hi');
        var itemBox = $(this)
        var itemHeight = itemBox.height();
        alert(itemHeight);
    })
});
```